# Converting rpart output into JSON Format in R

Tags: javascript, json, r

I have to plot decision tree in interactive mode which I can do in JavaScript, but to do this I need rpart object in Json format.

So I want to convert the rpart output into the JSON format using some library.

```
model <- rpart(formula=Species~Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+  
         Petal.Width,data=iris,na.action = na.rpart, method = "class",  
         parms = list(split="gini"),  
         control = rpart.control(minsplit= 10, cp= 0.005))

print(model)
```

Output

```
 n= 150 

  node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

 1) root 150 100 setosa (0.33333333 0.33333333 0.33333333)  
   2) PetalLength< 2.45 50   0 setosa (1.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000) *
   3) PetalLength>=2.45 100  50 versicolor (0.00000000 0.50000000 0.50000000)  
     6) PetalWidth< 1.75 54   5 versicolor (0.00000000 0.90740741 0.09259259)  
      12) PetalLength< 4.95 48   1 versicolor (0.00000000 0.97916667 0.02083333) *
      13) PetalLength>=4.95 6   2 virginica (0.00000000 0.33333333 0.66666667) *
     7) PetalWidth>=1.75 46   1 virginica (0.00000000 0.02173913 0.97826087) *
```

Can any one please tell me how do I convert rpart object into Json?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: So did you finished this?

Answer (score 3):

We can manually write a JSON parser using a recursive function. Here's a small example. Please note the following;

1. Writing a parser is easier for a "party" object than for a "rpart" object. Fortunately, we can convert any "rpart" object to "party" using as.party()
2. This is just a simple implementation to show the functionality. We can add other features at each node like the node_size, node_parent etc.

   ```
   install.packages('partykit')    
   json_prsr <- function(tree, node = 1, node_stats = NULL){

       # Checking the decision tree object
       if(!is(tree, c("constparty","party")))
           tree <- partykit::as.party(tree)

       # Parsing into json format
       str  <- ""
       rule <- partykit:::.list.rules.party(tree, node)

       if(is.null(node_stats))
           node_stats <- table(tree$fitted[1])
       children <- partykit::nodeids(tree, node)

       if (length(children) == 1) {
           ct  <- node_stats[as.character(children)]
           str <- paste("{","'name': '",children,"','size':",ct,",'rule':'",rule,"'}", sep='')
       } else {
           str <- paste("{","'name': '", node,"', 'rule': '", rule, "', 'children': [", sep='')
           for(child in children){
               check <- paste("{'name': '", child, "'", sep='')
               if(child != node & ( !grepl(check, str, fixed=TRUE) ) ) {
                   child_str <- json_prsr(tree, child, node_stats)
                   str <- paste(str, child_str, ',', sep='')
               }
           }
           str <- substr(str, 1, nchar(str)-1) #Remove the comma
           str <- paste(str,"]}", sep='')
       }
       return(str)
   }
   ```

Check the validity of the output JSON using by pasting the json string at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: would you mind if I implement this in https://github.com/timelyportfolio/d3r?  I have a couple local scripts to do similar, and I would like to try to integrate them.  Thanks.

Comment: No issues. :) (Y)